# How can I access O365 from asp.net web form

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi

I am working on an asp.net web form that has users with different O365 serviceses.
I mean they are not on the same AD, but come from different businesses.

I'm think they need to enter a username and password for their own system and then read the information.

Is there a way to access this calender information in C#?

I know there is Microsoft Graph, but can it be used with only a username and password without creating an applikation in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

MS Graph is the most stable and efficient way of accessing O365 information nowadays. However, you may still use EWS or Outlook REST APIs, see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.

Here is what MS states in MSDN:

> Microsoft recommends using Microsoft Graph to access Outlook mail, calendar, and contacts. You should use the Outlook APIs directly (via `https://outlook.office.com/api`) only if you require a feature that is not available on the Graph endpoints.

See [Overview of using the Outlook REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started) for information.